# Mongoose create multiple document if not exists

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I try to create an API with MongoDB and Node express (first time in node.js).

I made the following routes, which aims to save multiple file (unique) in mongoDB with a JSON input (which comes from an external request) :

```js
router.post('/sessions', function (req, res, next) {
    // invoke sessions update
    var config = {
        method: 'get',
        url: 'https://blabla',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json;version=0.1',
            'Accept-Language': 'fr',
        }
    };

    axios(config)
        .then(function (response) {
            for (const session of response.data) {
                doc = UserSimple.findOne({id: session.recipient.id}).then(function (doc) {
                    if (!doc) {
                        var newUser = new UserSimple(session.recipient)
                        newUser.save()
                    }
                })
            }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
});
```

From my codes, it seems that I do not understand correctly the "Promises", as my code try to fetch all document, and then save (because None exists when the promises are made) it in MongoDB:

```
Mongoose: usersimples.findOne({ id: 146299 }, { projection: {} })
Mongoose: usersimples.findOne({ id: 11676365 }, { projection: {} })
Mongoose: usersimples.findOne({ id: 11427231 }, { projection: {} })
Mongoose: usersimples.findOne({ id: 11676365 }, { projection: {} })
Mongoose: usersimples.findOne({ id: 146299 }, { projection: {} })
Mongoose: usersimples.findOne({ id: 11676365 }, { projection: {} })
Mongoose: usersimples.findOne({ id: 11676365 }, { projection: {} })
Mongoose: usersimples.findOne({ id: 481020 }, { projection: {} })
Mongoose: usersimples.findOne({ id: 11427231 }, { projection: {} })
Mongoose: usersimples.findOne({ id: 11427231 }, { projection: {} })
Mongoose: usersimples.findOne({ id: 146299 }, { projection: {} })
Mongoose: usersimples.findOne({ id: 11676365 }, { projection: {} })
Mongoose: usersimples.findOne({ id: 481020 }, { projection: {} })
Mongoose: usersimples.findOne({ id: 146299 }, { projection: {} })
Mongoose: usersimples.findOne({ id: 11676365 }, { projection: {} })
Mongoose: usersimples.findOne({ id: 11427231 }, { projection: {} })
Mongoose: usersimples.findOne({ id: 11676365 }, { projection: {} })
Mongoose: usersimples.findOne({ id: 481020 }, { projection: {} })
Mongoose: usersimples.findOne({ id: 146299 }, { projection: {} })
Mongoose: usersimples.findOne({ id: 11427231 }, { projection: {} })
Mongoose: usersimples.insertOne({ _id: ObjectId("60b8910526436428a409f6a9")....., id: 11676365 })
...
Mongoose: usersimples.insertOne({ _id: ObjectId("60b8910526436428a409f6ab")....., id: 11676365 })
```

What I want to do is, check if a document exist in MongoDB, if not create it; thus inside the same "request", if I have duplicate within my JSON input, only unique document will be created.
I imagine that this kind of "problem" is common, but I didn't find any resources to solve it .

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `save` is not awaited and thus you might end up in a situation where one document hasn't yet been saved while the loop continues with other JSON-documents, possibly the same as the one being saved.

Rewrite using async/await:

```
try {
    const response = await axios(config);
    let doc;
    for (const session of response.data) {
        doc = await UserSimple.findOne({ id: session.recipient.id });
        if (!doc) {
            var newUser = new UserSimple(session.recipient);
            await newUser.save();
        }
    }

} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Christian, your answer helps me a lot!